# Select to pull Zip code based both foreign and domestic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, zipcode, postal-code

I need to write a T-SQL procedure where the parameter is zip code. We've got the following parameter declared.

```
declare @postal_code varchar(10)
```

Sample data in table:

| postal_codes |
| --- |
| NULL |
| 46383 |
| 074523632 |
| B4H34 |
| 113601419 |
| ZH/8600 |
| A1G 9Z9 |
| WN73R |
| Wd3 3he |
| 89136 |

etc. We've got a variety of addresses some having no postal code for certain foreign countries to some having your standard 5 digit or 10 digit US postal codes.

I need to code the query in some way to say:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where postal_code = @postal_code
```

My initial code was this:

```
select *   
from table_name 
where (@postal_code is null or 
       left(ad.postal_code, 5) = @postal_code)
```

but this doesn't work for anything other then 5 digit ones, then I tried using 10 digit ones but the 5 digit ones didn't match. Do I need to strip spaces or other characters? I tried searching and there is a variety of solutions but I need something that works for all kinds of zip codes foreign and domestic.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I'm not following.  You need a WHERE clause based on the value of a parameter?  What's wrong with `postal_code = @postal_code`?  You should include sample source data and your desired results here.

Comment: @squillman it seems that when a user enters 10023, it needs to match it to those with 10023, 10023-0001, 10023-000X and those who put in 100231001, etc. It has to match it to all of the possibilities .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment it sounds like you need a "starts with" query.  Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE REPLACE(postal_code, ' ', '') LIKE REPLACE(@postal_code, ' ', '') + '%';
```

Comment: I don't think this would work for the following scenarios if someone enters this A1G 9Z9, I would need this A1G9Z9 as well as A1G 9Z9. It is not just a starting field. I am not sure how to encompass all scenarios.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Edited my answer

Comment: At some point you'll have to draw the line and determine when enough's enough.  You can't possibly account for every instance of idiocy in user inputs...